# Is this a type of polymorphism in object-oriented programming?

Tags: c#, oop

```
static void Main(string[] args)
 {
    string str = "abc";
    str += "xyz";
    Console.WriteLine(str);
 }
```

Here is **+=** a type of polymorphism?

Comment: I don't think you understand the concept of OOP.

Comment: @RUJordan the op is not talking about `OOP`. He's talking about *"Oops!"* as in *"Oops! I did it again..."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **Operator Overloading**, not Polymorphism, which in this case does string concatenation.
You can find more information on Operator Overloading at this location: [MSDN Link to Operator Overloading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/8edha89s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: `+=` operator can't be overloaded. `+=` evaluates to `+` which can be overloaded, but **in case of string it is not overloaded**. It is just the compiler which translates the call to `string.Concat`

Comment: So why *isn't* overloading a supportive demonstration of [Ad hoc Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hoc_polymorphism)?

Answer (score 6):

No, its not polymorphism its [string concatenation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228504.aspx)

[Polymorphism (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx) (base-derived class based)

> Polymorphism is often referred to as the third pillar of
>   object-oriented programming, after encapsulation and inheritance.
>   Polymorphism is a Greek word that means "many-shaped" and it has two
>   distinct aspects:
>
> - At run time, objects of a derived class may be treated as objects of a base class in places such as method parameters and collections or
>     arrays. When this occurs, the object's declared type is no longer
>     identical to its run-time type.
> - Base classes may define and implement virtual methods, and derived classes can override them, which means they provide their own
>     definition and implementation. At run-time, when client code calls the
>     method, the CLR looks up the run-time type of the object, and invokes
>     that override of the virtual method. Thus in your source code you can
>     call a method on a base class, and cause a derived class's version of
>     the method to be executed.

**Edit**, There are different types of Polymorphism as mentioned in this MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9k8e08x%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

> **Interface polymorphism** - Multiple classes may implement the same interface, and a single class may implement one or more interfaces.
>   Interfaces are essentially definitions of how a class needs to
>   respond. An interface describes the methods, properties, and events
>   that a class needs to implement, and the type of parameters each
>   member needs to receive and return, but leaves the specific
>   implementation of these members up to the implementing class.
>
> **Inheritance polymorphism** - Multiple classes may inherit from a single base class. By inheriting, a class receives all of the methods,
>   properties, and events of the base class in the same implementation as
>   the base class. Additional members can then be implemented as needed,
>   and base members can be overridden to provide different
>   implementations. Note that an inherited class may also implement
>   interfaces — the techniques are not mutually exclusive.
>
> **Polymorphism through abstract classes** - Abstract classes provide elements of both inheritance and interfaces. An abstract class is a
>   class that cannot be instantiated itself; it must be inherited. Some
>   or all members of the class might be unimplemented, and it is up to
>   the inheriting class to provide that implementation. Members that are
>   implemented might still be overridden, and the inheriting class can
>   still implement addition interfaces or other functionality.

Comment: You should probably put the quote in blockquotes, since it's lifted unmodified from the msdn link.

Comment: Can you explain it with reference. subtype polymorphism allows a function to be written to take an object of a certain type T, but also work correctly if passed an object that belongs to a type S that is a subtype of T, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)

Comment: Thanks @user2864740, you are talking about Interface Polymorphism. Now I added that in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

`a += b` naturally means `a = a + b`. In the case of strings, the `+` operator concatenates the second string onto the first. It's not an overloaded function (which I suspect is what you mean), but rather an overloaded operator, which by definition is a specific kind of polymorphism. So the simple answer is yes, but perhaps not in the way you think.

Comment: "In object-oriented programming, operator overloading—less commonly known as operator ad hoc polymorphism—is a specific case of polymorphism" - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading

Comment: Ah, okay, fair enough. Polymorphism it is.